# Is 「太太」("wife") pejorative? Archaic?

Tags: words, chinese

Jisho gives no example sentences using this term. Is it now considered archaic, pejorative, provincial? Would one use it referring to oneself, to someone else?

Comment: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A4%AA%E5%A4%AA says "特に、裕福な夫に依存し、働いていない妻を指す", but without citing any sources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kanji, but it's not Japanese. It's Chinese, meaning one's wife, and is often used to address the title of a married woman, just like 'Mrs.'. e.g. 陈（Chen）太太 is simply Mrs. Chen.

太太 now has a derivative meaning of "skilled artist", but only amongst Chinese Anime fandom. You probably saw someone using this in Pixiv's comment section or X. And interestingly, this word is gender-neutral if it's referring to an artist. A male artist could be referred to as "太太" by his fan.

Comment: I saw it in Jisho.

Comment: If you learn Japanese long enough, you will realize that it's common for you to find Chinese words in 辞书(Jisho). And if that word is strictly a Chinese word, it would be denoted '中国語'(Chinese) in Japanese Jisho. Just like you would find the word 'eureka' in almost all English dictionaries, but that word is strictly Greek.

Comment: Thank you! I will mark yours as the accepted answer because your comment above, more than your answer alone, makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

That is a Chinese word, both according to [Jisho](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%A4%AA%E5%A4%AA) and [Goo dictionary](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%A4%AA%E5%A4%AA_%28%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%29/#jn-133821):

> **タイタイ【太太】**
> 《(中国語)》奥様。夫人。

Not sure if pejorative; please refer to the [Chinese SE](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/). This word isn't used in Japanese with this meaning.

Comment: If it is strictly a Chinese word, rather than one borrowed from China, why does Jisho include it?

Comment: @NattoYum Good question; sadly, I don't know why. Goo dictionary and Weblio also include it for whatever the reason.

Comment: Wikipedia has an English language article about "[Tai tai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tai_tai)", but that doesn't mean the typical person will understand what you're talking about if you use it in English. I wouldn't be surprised if a large, comprehensive English dictionary had it as well.

Comment: Why is it there?  It looks like it sourced that entry from JMDict, which provides a (dubious) history: https://www.edrdg.org/jmwsgi/entr.py?svc=jmdict&sid=&q=2727430.1

Comment: "These Chinese terms worry me." Me too, Jim Breen, me too... ️